# SELECT DISTINCT any value if the WHERE conditions weren't met

Tags: mysql

So I have a table containing 3 columns with the data I want, productname, productmanufacturer and productcategory.

It looks like this:

```
MariaDB [foundationtests]> select * from products_tbl;
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
| product_id | product_name | product_manufacturer | product_category |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
|         12 | i5           | intel                | computer         |
|         14 | swimsuit     | adidas               | sports           |
|         17 | Die Elfen    | Heyne                | books            |
|         19 | Die Zwerge   | Heyne                | books            |
|         20 | gym shoes    | adidas               | sports           |
|         22 | i7           | intel                | computer         |
|         24 | i3           | intel                | computer         |
|         25 | rope         | adidas               | sports           |
|         26 | Die Orks     | Heyne                | books            |
|         27 | Die Drachen  | Heyne                | books            |
|         28 | i8500        | intel                | computer         |
|         29 | bikershorts  | adidas               | sports           |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
12 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

I basically want to run the following query:

```
  $fetch = $connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT product_name
                                 FROM products_tbl
                                 WHERE product_manufacturer = ?
                                 OR product_category = ?

                             OR IF NONE OF THESE EXISTS
                             BEFORE THE SELECTLIMIT WAS REACHED 
                             SELECT ANY RECORD FROM
                             THE SPECIFIED COLUMN DISTINCT
                             FROM THE ALREADY FETCHED RESULTS

                             ORDER BY RAND()
                             LIMIT 6
                             ");
```

Is this possible with some short mysql Syntax?

EDIT:
Example for expected result:

Now lets assume product_manufacturer = ?  is matched against "intel" and 
product_category = ? is matched against "computer". 
In this case, 4 rows will be selected giving us "i5, i7, i3, i8500" as (randomized) resultset.
But I want a minimum of 6 rows, randomized, like "i5, Die Elfen, i7, i3, Swimsuit, i8500".

How can I achieve this in the query?

EDIT: Here is some extended sample data, since some problems become better visible if there are enough records on the table to potentially return a full resultset with record which actually MATCHED the WHERE criteria:

```
MariaDB [foundationtests]> select * from products_tbl;
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
| product_id | product_name | product_manufacturer | product_category |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
|         12 | i5           | intel                | computer         |
|         14 | swimsuit     | adidas               | sports           |
|         17 | Die Elfen    | Heyne                | books            |
|         19 | Die Zwerge   | Heyne                | books            |
|         20 | gym shoes    | adidas               | sports           |
|         22 | i7           | intel                | computer         |
|         24 | i3           | intel                | computer         |
|         25 | rope         | adidas               | sports           |
|         26 | Die Orks     | Heyne                | books            |
|         27 | Die Drachen  | Heyne                | books            |
|         28 | i8500        | intel                | computer         |
|         29 | bikershorts  | adidas               | sports           |
|         30 | i7399        | intel                | computer         |
|         31 | i6400        | intel                | computer         |
|         32 | i5473        | intel                | computer         |
|         33 | i9876        | intel                | computer         |
|         34 | i8888        | intel                | computer         |
|         35 | i9076        | intel                | computer         |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Expected results based on the example data are missing? See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'll edit it in.

Comment: Is product_name unique?

Comment: @forpas Yes it is unique. Its kind of overcommitting to ask for a solution which also takes care of giving only distinct results, but I wanted to make sure of that as well in case I change anything in the future (its just a testdatabase where I'm trying out stuff).

Comment: What in cases of ties?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Ties should be eliminated from the resultset. Since the goal would be to display the data to the logged in user, displaying the same pair of shoes twice wouldn't make much sense ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional sorting:

```
select * from (
  select product_name
  from products_tbl
  order by (product_manufacturer = 'Heyne' or product_category = 'computer') desc, rand()
 limit 6
)t
order by rand()
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b5cd8dba98ac903657ee5023edb5b1a4).

Comment: The problem is that I don't get all the matches on my first/mainquery. 
I WANT to get the results of 6 matches, if possible. If no 6 rows could be matched, I want to "fill up" the results with matches from rows which DONT match the criteria of the first/mainquery.

Comment: yes I did, this is the result:
swimsuit
rope
bikershorts
gym shoes
Die Elfen
i8500

And this is not what I wanted, see my OP.

Comment: By *this is not what I wanted* do you mean only the order of the results (because you want them randomized) or the rows returned are also wrong?

Comment: I just wondered: If more than 6 records are present, will the resultset always consist of the first 6 matches? Because this wouldn't be desired. Overall, of course assuming enough records are there, the resultsets of each consecutive query should be able to differ from each other, both in Order and contents

Comment: Innovative approach, but just a Heads up! This query wont be able to use indexing, and will definitely do a Full Table Scan; so would be inefficient on large tables (production usecase)!

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I guess you point at `rand()`, right? But isn't this the requirement? You use it too in your query.

Comment: No. My `RAND()` comes later at the end, when the resultset from `UNION` would have at max 18 rows only. Moreover, due to using `WHERE` conditions and `LIMIT` clauses in the inner select queries, MySQL would really be reading limited rows only (if appropriate indexes are defined). @baryon123 Please define indexes (if not defined) on `product_manufacturer` and `product_category` separately, and run `explain..` statement on both the queries to see the difference.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya what is there to compare? Your query does not meet the requirement. Read the comments under my answer.

Comment: @forpas I cant get the query to run, here is the php I'm trying to do:
https://rextester.com/VLB90248 

But I get an empty resultset. The productAttributes contain values though, so something must go wrong on queryside

Comment: The query is fine and you can see it in the demo.

Comment: @forpas Okay, what does the "t" do after the closing outter bracket of the SELECT query?

Comment: It is the alias for the subquery and it is needed in both MySql and MariaDB.

Comment: @forpas thanks I got your query to run now, however, it still doesnt work 100% as it is supposed to:
Currently, it selects a random number of rows matching the criteria of the subquery. It can be any number as long as its not above 6. This is not desired. I want the query to retrieve up to 6 rows if there are enough records to select from. If there are 7 matching records, then 6 shall be selected, ALWAYS. Only if there isn't enough records, then the remaining X rows shall be filled from other records not meeting the criteria of the subquery.

Comment: @forpas okay for some reason, it works now. I have NO idea what I did wrong when copypasta. Really, very sorry I made this more complicated than necessary. BIG thanks to you, I'll accept your answer immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize `UNION ALL` with two `SELECT` queries; in the first query, you can get 6 rows corresponding to the matching condition; we will also get an additional column `matching` informing us that the result is from matching condition.

Now, in the second query, traditional way would be to do `SELECT.. WHERE NOT EXISTS (..<matching condition SELECT query> ..) LIMIT 6`. However, this would be relatively inefficient. So we can avoid this `NOT EXISTS` condition, and instead fetch 12 rows (two times the first query rows). This would ensure that even if the first query's 6 rows are returned by the second query, we still have a buffer for another 6 rows.

Note that `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is indeterminate, but since you want random ordering only; we can avoid by `ORDER BY` in the internal `SELECT` queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt.product_name 
FROM 
(
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_name, '1' AS matching
    FROM products_tbl
    WHERE product_manufacturer = ?
          OR product_category = ? 
    LIMIT 6
  )

  UNION ALL 

  (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_name, '0' AS matching 
    FROM products_tbl
    LIMIT 12
  )
) AS dt     
ORDER BY dt.matching DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes; but in this particular case, we have `DISTINCT`, so duplicates are avoided away.

Comment: .. to be fair i also upvoted this question as the topicstarter also seams not to care about a deterministic sort so also the reason i removed mine comments. As i didn't read the edit where the topicstarter is talking about a randomized resultset and didn't say what should happen in cases on ties..

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya I'm facing issues getting your proposal into my PDO prepared statement. Especially with the leading brackets in front of the queries. Could you give me a hint how can I put this code into the parameter of "$fetch->prepare();"?

Comment: @baryon123 please share your PHP code here: https://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya 
I posted the "full" php code in case you find it useful, but it suffices if you look at the function "fetchProductSelection(...)"

Comment: @baryon123 link ? Just put the specific php code there and click on "Save It" to generate a link.

Comment: @baryon123 try to avoid certain words in this place please. Your comment raised many flags from the automatic bots that scan this site to identify rude comments.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks I got the query to run!
However, it doesn't work as desired.
It seems the result from the first query and the result from the second query are halfed and then mashed together. What was desired was that only in case the first query doesn't match at least 6 rows, the remaining X results are filled with matches distinct from the matches before. Furthermore, it is always the first matches which are selected, instead I want a random selection of matches (e.g. match 1, 6, 10, 12, 16, 17) on every new query.

Comment: @baryon123 "result from the first query and the result from the second query are halfed and then mashed together" - this wont be happening, pls check carefully. Afree with the second part, it wont work for random matches everytime, but that generally is not the requirement of any pagination problem, and it would be inefficient too. You can go with forpas' answer, but it would be slow, if you have large table.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya But this is exactly whats happening, I get these contents in various orders over and over from my var_dump when I use your code:

array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "i7"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "i3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Die Zwerge"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Die Orks"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "i5"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Die Elfen"
  }
}